# If possibly exposed to COVID-19, can I use my best judgment?

Tags: covid-19, ohio, indiana

In most U.S. states, COVID-19 regulations such as wearing masks and social distancing are no longer mandated, at least not for people who don't have the virus. Are there laws in those states, such as in Ohio or Indiana, that nonetheless regulate people in other scenarios? For example, if someone has been exposed to COVID-19, are there any regulations they'd have to follow? Also, would a person's vaccination status or natural immunity (due to antibodies from already having had the virus) affect the answer?

And again, since the answer likely varies by state, I'll use Ohio and Indiana's jurisdictions for the purpose of this thread. Thanks!

Comment: For instance, there are usually laws that give state or local health authorities the power to order quarantines when necessary for public health.  They can do this case-by-case and there don't necessarily have to be well-defined criteria based on vaccination, immunity, etc.  These laws have existed for a very long time and are not specific to COVID-19.  Is that the kind of thing you would want to know about?

Comment: @NateEldredge I think so. For example, if I was exposed to someone who has been exposed to COVID-19 but don't think I have it, can I legally go by my best judgment, or are there laws I could be breaking? If it's case-by-case in these jurisdictions, then I assume that my best judgment would be legal, right?